# Installation of libglib2.0-dev on Fedora

Tags: cmake, glib

Recently, I switched from Ubuntu to Fedora. Now, I would like to run the Fedora equivalent to the Ubuntu command

`sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev`

Because when I `cmake` a project (in particular [lcm 1.4.0](https://lcm-proj.github.io/build_instructions.html)), the error is

`Could NOT find GLib2_glib (missing: GLIB2_GLIB_LIBRARY GLIB2_GLIB_INCLUDE_DIR GLIB2_GLIBCONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR)`

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent command is

```
sudo dnf install glib2-devel
```

This will install the glib 2 development headers, libraries and dependencies.